# Infimum of a function over a closed bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that for every $x\in[a,b]$ there exists a $y \in [a,b]$ such that $|f(y)|<\frac{1}{2}|f(x)|$. What is the infimum of $|f(x)|$ on $[a,b]$?

My idea:

Suppose $\inf\limits_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)|$ exists, then there exists $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $$|f(x_0)|\le |f(x)|, \hskip{0.2cm} \forall x\in [a,b]$$ Then by hypothesis, there exists a $y \in [a,b]$ such that $$|f(y)|\le \frac{1}{2}|f(x_0)|\le \frac{1}{2}|f(x)|$$

Thus, $|f(y)|\le 2|f(y)|<|f(x_0)|$, a contradiction to the infimum attained.

Are my arguments valid?

Comment: If a function is not continuous on a closed and bounded interval, then it needn't attain its infimum. Consider $f: [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(0) = 1$, and $f(x) = x$ otherwise.

Comment: right. you cannot assume such an $x_0$ is available.

Comment: Also, $\{\lvert f(x) \rvert : x \in [a, b]\}$ is bounded below, so surely the infimum does exist. This gives you some idea as to how you should proceed.

Comment: @WADon $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$ else there would exists $y\mid |f(y)|<0$ which is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the infimum of $|f|$ on the given interval $I$. Obviously $\theta \in [0,|f(a)|].$

Our $\theta$ must be zero, for if we suppose $\theta>0$, there must be $t \in I$ satisfying $|f(t)|<2\theta$.

Hence there exists $s \in I$ such that

$$|f(s)|\,\,<\,\,\frac{1}{2}\,|f(t)|\,\,<\,\,\theta.$$

Thus $\theta$ is not the infimum after all.